# Japanese text not showing correctly on PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, unicode, localization, internationalization

I'm am having some issues showing Japanese text on my English utf-8 website I have tried the following

`<?= $japan[artist];?>` but it prints out like this **`æ¤Žåæž—æªŽ`**

I have tried to encode it that does not even print it out and I have tried `html_entity_decode( $text, ENT_QUOTES, "utf-8" );`

If I knew how to encode the Japanese text into UTF-8 that would help I think, but I cant seem to find any information on this or the PHP function.

The database is MongoDB not MYSQL

It worths noting that the text gets saved in JapaneseA text and not utf-8

Comment: Did you remember to set the proper meta tags? `<meta charset='utf-8'>`

Comment: If data comes from MySQL DB, Then check also for locale set 'character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci'

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/24277493/3176270

Comment: If your website is already UTF-8 encoded properly, then this looks like a double encoding (if you used an UTF-8 capable feed reader for that itunes feed). Ensure the database has the data correctly and returns it as UTF-8 then.

Answer (score 1):

**I use Persian language and some time have this problem, I think it is not PHP problem,  maybe one of this suggestion is your answer:**

1-Change your editor  encoding to utf-8

2-If using database set it to `utf8_general_ci`

3-Add this html tag to head of your pages:

*old tag(HTML4)*

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

*and HTML5:*

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
```